# Applying a prebuilt theme in Angular 2 does not change anything

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to apply a Material prebuilt theme and it does not change the style of my app at all.  I am including the import statement

`@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";`

in my `styles.css` file, but nothing changes.  I've checked that my path to the file is correct and I've included Material's core in the file.  I also tried including

`<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

in `index.html` but that returned a 404 error.  Most fixes for prebuilt themes have been solved by just including the import in the `styles.css` file but that is not helping my situation.  I am using Angular CLI for this project.

Comment: What are you expecting to be changed? `<button md-raised-button color="primary">Test</button>` is one of the easiest indicators. Are you receiving any console errors/warning in your browser about not having a theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following import statement within your styles.css:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Taken from the [starting guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme). You will also need to apply most of the other steps.

As Z. Bagley suggests in the comments, `<button md-raised-button color="primary">Test</button>` would be an easy way to check, if the theme works (do not forget to include `MdButtonModule`).

Comment: I tried that as well, and I didn't get a 404 error but the app still did not change style.

Comment: Did you use UI-components from Angular Material, e.g. a button? And did you follow the whole starting guide?

Comment: I got it to work.  I was under the assumption that the theme would apply to the app once imported, but it only applies to Material objects.  Using the md-raised-button showed the theme.  Thanks for the help!